# How to access specific cells of a Dataframe and do some computation on them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
                Open            Close
2018-05-23  277.760010  279.070007
2018-05-24  278.399994  277.850006
2018-05-25  277.630005  278.850006
2018-05-26  0.0         0.0
2018-05-27  0.0         0.0
2018-05-28  0.0         0.0
2018-05-29  278.510010  283.760010
2018-05-30  283.290009  291.720001
```

what i need to do is to make an approximation of the Nan values by computing the mean of the previous Known open values and the next known open values.

For example, the Open value of 2018-05-26 would be:

277.630005 is the Value of the previous day
278.510010 is the value of three days after

so its approximation value is (277.630005 + 278.510010)/2

How is it possible to do such computation in such way to fill Open and Close values?

what i tried to do is:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Open'] == 0.0:
       ......
    if row['Close']== 0.0:
       .......

but i have no clue what i have to do
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `replace` and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
 df.replace(0,np.nan).interpolate()

                  Open       Close
2018-05-23  277.760010  279.070007
2018-05-24  278.399994  277.850006
2018-05-25  277.630005  278.850006
2018-05-26  277.850006  280.077507
2018-05-27  278.070007  281.305008
2018-05-28  278.290009  282.532509
2018-05-29  278.510010  283.760010
2018-05-30  283.290009  291.720001
```

Comment: `replace` replaces the zeros with `NaN`s and then `interpolate` interpolates what values the `NaN`s should be. You should read the `interpolate` docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function.

Comment: there is no method to get what i need. Do you have any other clue?

Comment: Vedo che ti ha già risposto l'amico qui sopra ;)